# Did I wire my light fixture correctly?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

I'm replacing a light fixture in an old apartment where the ceiling wiring has two brown/red wires and one black wire.  When I removed the old fixture it was wired with black to black, the white wire was extended with another white wire with a wire nut and then connected to the two brown/red wires.  The old fixture did not have a grounding wire. One of the brown/red wires seemed to be coming down directly from a small hole in the ceiling and the other brown/red wire was coming out from the side of the ceiling along with the black wire.

So, I took my new fixture and connected the black to black, the white to the brown/red that was next to the black and seemed to coming out of the side of the ceiling/junction box (terminology?) and then I connected my green grounding wire to the other brown/red wire that was coming down directly out of the small hole in the ceiling.

I would like to know did I wire this new fixture correctly? It seems to be working just fine and I even tested it with a voltage meter after I turned the power back on in case I didn't ground it correctly.

Comment: What makes you think that the wire you connected to was a ground? Did you perform any tests? It's very difficult to distinguish a ground from a neutral, and you shouldn't mix the two until you get to the main breaker panel.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds wrong to me, but I couldn't be *sure* without actually being there.  You should connect the new fixture, in exactly the same way the original fixture was connected.

If there wasn't a grounding conductor in the original circuit, replacing the fixture did not make one magically appear. If a grounding conductor is required, you'll have to install one in accordance with local codes.

Comment: If I connect the new fixture exactly as the old fixture was connected what do I do with the green wire on the new fixture.

Comment: @C.R Leave it disconnected.  If you follow NEC you'll have to either install a proper grounding conductor, or protect the outlet with a GFCI device.

Answer (score 1):

The wires in my house are exactly the same.  Everything is run with old cotton braided wires inside a metal BX shielding.  **The reddish-brownish wire is neutral; the black wire is hot.**

**So no, you did not hook this up correctly.**  You should keep it hooked up the way it was before, with the white lamp-wire spliced to the two red/brown wall-wires, and the black lamp-wire spliced to the black wall-wire.

---

The grounding was provided by the metal BX jacket *(which is electrically-connected to the lamp via the metal box)*.  This is not allowed by the NEC anymore, and for good reason:  BX cable has [high impedance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance), meaning it does not provide a good electrical connection to ground.

Running a ground wire through the BX cable is extremely difficult (I've tried it).  Thus, I'd recommend you install a GFCI at the start of the circuit and connect everything else (including the lamp) to the 'load' side.  This is [required for 3-prong outlets](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/31179/31200#31200), and though I don't have the NEC to verify, I would assume the same is true for other fixtures.

Comment: If I connect the new fixture exactly as the old fixture was connected what do I do with the green wire on the new fixture?

Comment: @C.R The green wire is [ground](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/31179/31182#31182), so the light will work fine if you leave it connected to nothing.  Since the BX jacket *(the flexible metal tubing that protects the wires in the wall)* is grounded and electrically connected to the metal electrical box the light sits in, I've been tying the green wire to the box, but as I mentioned this is not strictly to code.  To be to code, you will either need to run a separate ground wire to the fixture somehow, or attach a GFCI to the beginning of the circuit.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The GFCI device can be anywhere in the circuit, as long as it protects the new fixture. However, you're correct that installing a combination GFCI breaker is probably the easiest option, as it provides protection to the entire circuit.

Comment: I'd note that for a ceiling lamp, ground is less of an issue, as it will be rare for anyone (but you) to be touching it while showering/bathing/etc.  Replacing the fixture in general does not trigger new code requirements.